# Lagom with SSL/TLS

Tags: lagom

Is it possible to configure Lagom to work with SSL/TLS connections?

1. I generated keystore and trustore files using Java KeyTool,
2. I tried to configure play framework in the application.conf file to work with the generated files with no success.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you had in more detail?

Comment: I'm working on client (Reactjs) - server (Lagom) microservices application.
Lagom's framework configure the services to work on http and everything work as expected when the client sends regular http request to the server.
But now I want to use secure connection via https but the client cannot connect to server due to the pre-configured http protocol by the framework.
So, in the past few dayes, I tried to find out how can I configure the framework to work\listen to https request. Also,Lagom is based on play and akka so I tried to find a workaround using these frameworks as well.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180431/why-isnt-my-server-requesting-a-client-cert-in-play-2-6-x) question/answer might help you. I used this in a Lagom app.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.5.x Lagom version, the use of SSL has been supported:
https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/ConfiguringServicesInDevelopment.html#Using-HTTPS-in-development-mode